# Calculating the norms of a triangle based pyramid

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, 3d

Hi I have the following co-ordinates, which make up my triangle based pyramid. I need to calculate the normals of each face. However Im struggling to find the best simplest way to do this?

```
-0.5, 0, 0.5,
 0, 0, -0.5,
0.5, 0, 0.5,

0, 0, -0.5,
0.5, 0, 0.5,
0, 1, 0,

-0.5, 0, 0.5,
0, 0, -0.5,
0, 1, 0,

0.5, 0, 0.5,
-0.5, 0, 0.5,
0, 1, 0
```

[image]

Comment: What is the norm of a face? Do you mean its area?

Comment: No I meant the normal. Ive added a picture to clarify. I believe the technical term is: a line from the origin, which is perpendicular to the face it passes through.

Comment: @geminiCoder If you're making models that you intend to use in a Direct3D engine, using Maya / 3DS Max and then exporting the model to .obj file format can save you time. It automatically calculates the norms (lines that begin with `vn`. The norm of a plane $ax+by+cz+d=0$ is $(a,b,c)$. You may normalize it. Also, the cross product of two non-parallel vectors in the plane is perpendicular to the plane, like @enzotib 's answer.

Comment: Look up Newell's algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given three non aligned point of a face, say $A, B, C$, build the vectors
$$
\mathbf{u}=B-A,\\
\mathbf{v}=C-A.
$$
The vector $\mathbf{n}=\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v}$ is normal to the given face, you should only normalize its length.

---

Take
$$
A=(-1/2, 0, 1/2),\\
B=(0, 0, -1/2),\\
C=(1/2, 0, 1/2),
$$
then build
$$
\mathbf{u}=B-A=(  0, 0, -1/2)-(-1/2, 0, 1/2)=(1/2,0,-1),\\
\mathbf{v}=C-A=(1/2, 0,  1/2)-(-1/2, 0, 1/2)=(1,0,0).
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{n}=\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v}=\left|
\begin{matrix}
i &j &k\\
1/2 &0 &-1\\
1 &0 &0
\end{matrix}
\right|=(0,-1,0)
$$
The resulting vector is, in this particular case, already normalized.

Comment: I know its a bit cheeky, but could you give me and example using the co-ordinates above. I would be most grateful!

Comment: Thanks thats fantastic. I appreciate your time

Comment: For consistency, one would want to ensure that the vertices of the polygons are all "clockwise" or "anticlockwise" before computing the normals, lest one obtain a result where some of the normals are pointing "outside" the pyramid, and the others are pointing "inside".